# Basic mysql query giving no results

Tags: php, mysql

I got a simple query looking like this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("host","username","password","default_database");

if(mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `users_t`";
    $result = mysqli_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo $row['email'];
    }

}
```

Running this query gives me absolutely nothing. No errors but no result at the same time. I can't figure out whats wrong, help me please.

Comment: What does your schema look like?  Do you have data in that table?

Comment: The table `users_t` does have data in it. It contains 8 different columns where `email` is one of them.

Comment: Can you put in one or two columns into the select statement that you know has data and also append a piece of text onto the echo in the while loop to make sure that your actually getting into the while loop?

Comment: @atallon Thank you for mentioning to add text in the while loop. I used the code Joshua Burns posted below and it works. I figured out the problem: the email addresses contains special characters, namely "@"! The query problem is fixed, now just to fix this.

Comment: I have a hard time seeing how an @ character would be problematic.  That is a pretty standard character that should be supported no matter what encoding you're using.  You might try replacing your `echo` line with `var_dump($row);` to see what's actually in that $row variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there may be a few things going on here:

1. According to the [mysqli_connect_errno() Documentation](http://php.net/mysqli_connect_errno), you should be checking for `!$con` rather than `mysqli_connect_errno($con)` in your `if` statement.
2. When a connection error is encountered, you're calling the error function but not printing it.
3. According to the [mysqli_query() documentation](http://php.net/mysqli_query), the first argument should be the database connection, the second being the query itself.
4. When a query errors out, you're calling `mysql_error()` when you should be calling `mysqli_error()`, passing it the connection. Again, according to [documentation](http://php.net/mysqli_error)

Try this out and see if this resolves your problems:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("host","username","password","default_database");

if(!$con) {
  print mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `users_t`";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die (mysqli_error($con));
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['email'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly, turns out the problem was the email addresses containing special characters. Using your code I can retrieve other fields containing normal letters (its the @ messing it up when getting email addresses). Should I change my database encryption?

Comment: encryption won't solve your problem.. you could change it's encoding to something like UTF-8 though, that may solve your problems.

Comment: I'm using UTF-8 encoding and the VARCHAR data type for the email column, does VARCHAR support "@"?

Comment: `@` isn't even a special character, it's part of the ASCII standard. UTF-8 is an expansion of the ASCII standard. What is the exact error you're receiving? I don't think it's the `@` character...

Comment: Tried it just now and it works, turns out I had a typo in the column name...history repeats itself I guess. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
```

Needs a mysqli resource link and also its not `mysql_error()`

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($con,$query))
{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo $row['email'];
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is case-sensitive, so there is a very good change that your column in the database is actually named `Email` and then you have no result when you check `$row['email']`, because the `E` has to be upper case.

What you can do is make sure you use the right case in PHP, or select just the fields you want. MYSQL isn't case-senstive, so if you do the following it will work.

Also a good way to check if you have the right case: use `var_dump($row)` (I've added it to the code just to show you)

```
$con = mysqli_connect("host","username","password","default_database");

if(mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
    $query = "SELECT email FROM `users_t`";
    $result = mysqli_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo $row['email'];
        var_dump($row);
    }

}
```